# Reading from big json data in java

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

To start off, I'm pretty new in `programming`. I have to create an `Android` Weather App for a school project and I'm stuck with this big ass `JSON`:

[JSON Data](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Maribor&units=metric&APPID=79d5a2d4dec4a5e84034fc6357fa111c)

Out of this, how would I read the temperature out of every 3 hour interval(example: 9.00-12.00 temperature: 5°C, 12.00-15.00 temperature: 7°C etc.).
So I have an `Activity` that displays the temperature of the entire day by three hour intervals. Since I have no experience with JSON I have no idea what the certain indexes mean, when does it increment(there are like 8 main: thingies).

DISCLAIMER: I have to use JSON, no GSON or other shortcuts, I have to parse and read certain data from this JSON. I get this JSON from open weather map API so it changes every day. 
[API](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Maribor&units=metric&APPID=79d5a2d4dec4a5e84034fc6357fa111c)

Comment: JSON is a data representation, by simply expressing your data in JSON, you are "using JSON". So, it's unclear from your question what you're looking for here since you say you "have to use JSON". Ultimately you will need some JSON parser.

Comment: Please post the code you currently have, even if it doesn't work, and the output or errors it currently produces. Without that it will be difficult for anyone to help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a parser? Or are you intended to parse it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Use [volly](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) library for it. You can easily fetch data from json. No async task is needed, if you are using volly library.

Answer (score 0):

1. First validate the json by going to http://jsonlint.com/. This will help you see the formatted Json string.
2. Next read up on Json array and Object .
3. Use AsynTask to get the Json into forecastJsonStr string.
4. Then you need to convert this forecastJsonStr into JSon object forecastJsonObj

To get weather data in "list" do something similar to

```
JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray("list");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject receivedData = new JSONObject("The string that you get as response from the API");
JSONArray weatherList = receivedData.getJSONArray("list");
for(int i=0;i<weatherList.length();i++){
    JSONObject data = weatherList.getJSONObjectAt(i);
    String date_text - data.getString("dt_txt");
    JSONArray weatherData = weatherList.getJSONArray("main");
    for(int j=0;j<weatherData.length();j++){
        // Here is where you will get all the weather stuff that you need
        int temp = weatherData.getInt("temp");
        // Similarly other values like temp_min, temp_max
    }
}
```

So basically you need to parse the entire thing. In order to understand the whole structure more clearly use something like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ in order to view the JSON in a more clear way so that you know what you need from the JSON data better. Simple copy paste your data into there and click "Format".

JSON is just a name-value pair kind of storage if you see stored like "name":"value". Integer values don't have the "".

Remember all the JSON is stored in { } and a JSON can be nested in a JSON. So in your example if you see, the entire thing is a JSON. Within that you have a "city" key which has a value within { }. So "city" is a JSONObject.

Similarly "coord" is a JSONObject while "cod" is a String and "cnt" is an integer.

There can also be some instances where a name points to an array of JSON objects like "list" over here. JSON Arrays are signified using a [ ]. Enclosed within are JSON objects separated by comma.

Above is a very simple sample to get you started so that you get a jist of what is going on. So play around and try to extract more data from in there.

All the best and Happy Coding :)